# How do you upload the mind of someone already deceased?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, consciousness, data-storage, mind

I have a situation where the military generals and high leadership are mind-uploaded, AI reconstructed philosophers and brilliant strategists of historical times. I can't, however, figure out how the mind-upload can accurately reflect the actual person. For example, if I were to want to upload the mind of julius caesar, I wouldn't have enough historical documentation and information about his personality and traits to upload and have an accurate emulation of him. How else could I create a reconstruction?

Comment: We're not a brainstorming site. How do you expect this question to not have many equally valid answers? Please remember that questions with many valid answers are not permitted here.

Comment: > accurate emulation of him It can't be done, the best you can do is superimpose whatever is special about him that you can find or fits your agenda upon a generic template of some sort, perhaps a template for egomaniacal conquerors which you could also use for Ghengis Khan etc,. Then separate base templates for philosophers and other things.

Comment: The question could be improved in a couple ways: Mind-uploading is a sci-fi technology which doesn't exist yet, so you'll have to describe the process a little bit more. If your imaginary process simply requires a brain, then you won't be able to do the upload on a long-dead person. Also, it might help to know what the goal is... what is a historical figure anyway? A historical figure is in some sense an artificial creation that reflects an actual human being; maybe your AIs will be happy enough to embody the character rather than try to replicate the actual person.

Comment: @Zwuwdz The phrase "mind-uploaded" isn't actually relevant to the question. That's just a bit of backstory banter. The OP's question is only how to obtain enough information about a deceased individual (any deceased individual) such that a personality-accurate simulation could be created. How that simulation is created isn't relevant to the information-gathering process.

Comment: Time-machine anyone?

Comment: C. Julius Caesar was an egomaniacal conqueror? A much more common opinion is that he was a clear-sighted politician who saw what was wrong with the Roman state and did his best to fix it. (And his fix worked for about 200 years. Not bad.)

Comment: @AlexP opinion is relative, in his own day a LOT of people would not have been fans of his. He didn't come from nowhere first he slaughtered a bunch of Gauls and others before and in between his political grandstanding which ended with him lying in a puddle of his own blood without a son to even take up his reins. Total failure if looked at some ways.

Comment: A very relevant SF story: [A Work of Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Work_of_Art) by James Blish.

Comment: Relevant story: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days (using information-only wormholes from the past to copy the brain pattern before death)

Comment: In Greg Egan's story, “A Kidnapping” there is a subplot about the narrator's mother, who has been uploaded and is enjoying a perfect afterlife.  Except she misses her former husband, who died before uploading was possible. But her mind, which is preserved perfectly, contains her own mental model of her husband, and this is enough to construct a simulation of him which she finds satisfactory, even if everyone else perceives it as fake.

Comment: And in _Diaspora_ a famous mathematician of the past is reconstructed by interpolating from her published papers and interviews. The reconstruction isn't like the real person was, and can't do any breakthrough mathematics, but she is useful as a tutor and conversational partner for real people studying and trying to extend her work.

Comment: As you've asked the question with ancient historical persons, the answer is simply "you don't", at least not without a lot of magic or magical bullshit you pretend isn't magic but science, which utterly breaks immersion/suspension-of-disbelief. Uploading someone who just died, recently died, or somehow had their body preserved very well is a very different question from bullshitting a person out of scraps of historical evidence, and I think it would help a lot to decide *which one you actually want to do* and focus on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want anything too fantastical in your story, you can always build on a **useful and unexpected scientific discovery** that sets your world in motion. This can consist mostly of technobabble that is vaguely feasible, but not necessary for the reader to understand.

##### Setting up the science

For example: when studying the mind as a dynamical system, researchers find that the state space of possible minds is remarkably low-dimensional. That is, even though fully measuring a brain requires billions of measurements, most of these can be predicted from the others. What's more, a mind's trajectory is governed by various attractors, which means that if you can pinpoint a mind at a particular point in time, and correct for major life events, you can simulate very accurately how they will respond to certain situations.

*Note that this doesn't require perfect predictions of what they will say or do. It just requires that we can accurately model a probability distribution over likely choices.*

Of course, we've had 100 billion humans over the course of history, and most of them are pretty distinct, so that's the number of possible minds we should be able to distinguish between, at the minimum, to have our simulated Caesar be more than an extended personality type. This means we should be able to answer at least 37 yes/no questions before we can separate Caesar's mind from all the other minds in human history. If we up that to 50, which shouldn't be too much given how well Caesar's life has been documented, we get a world in which there are about 10<sup>15</sup> possible people.

##### Building Caesar

How then do we find these 50 yes/no questions? We simulate. We start with a crude simulation of Caesar's mind built by traditional means like LLM training, and simple wargames. This should get us in the ballpark. We then look for times in Caesar's life when he made a decision, where our current model-Caesar makes a very *different* decision in a crude simulation. Or more technically, his distribution over the possible actions, assigns the action taken by the actual Caesar a low probability.

We then craft a far more accurate simulation of this point in time, use the choice point to move to a better attractor in the mind state-space, and we repeat the process. The documented life of Caesar allows us for hundreds of these choice points (each costing many millions of dollars to create), after which we can say with high certainty that we have the right attractor, and we've pinpointed the *actual Caesar*.

We then enrich this mind with all the memories that we know of the actual Caesar and for anything we don't know, we add fictional memories that don't throw the mind off its attractor.

##### Validating the method

Ok, so we're a few pages of exposition further and we now a have a "simulated Caesar" that is better than a crude AI pretending to be Caesar. How do we know that we have in some sense the actual Ceasar. It's fine if it's surprising how well the method works, lots of scientific discoveries work remarkably well (LLM training, the atomic bomb, gravity assists). The main thing is that extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.

Here, the validation is that *it works on people who are still alive*. In fact, the method is far too expensive to be used as a simple aid to wargaming. Such a use case wouldn't justify the thousand of billions that went into its development.

No, the method emerged from intelligence agencies building models of important individuals in other countries. Knowing how the US president and his cabinet will react to certain actions and offers is gold dust to the Chinese government and vice versa. There's an organic route from doing what they are already doing to adding in AI technology, and any and all computational psychology they can get their hands on, to make better predictions. Once the models start to prove themselves, it's easy to funnel billions into improving them, especially if you know the other guys are doing the same.

After a while, it turned out that each country basically had a perfect copy of the other's president. This could be validated, for instance, by taking a public interview given by the president, or a diplomatic conversation, and creating a high-fidelity simulation of it. Time after time, it turned out the clone responded exactly the same, down to the length of pauses, and the choice of words. There were slight deviations, but these were very limited.  **Everybody was very astonished, but that's how things turned out to work.**

Finally, the secret got out, and using the technology on living people was outlawed. However, for historical characters, born sufficiently long ago, the law was left up to each individual country to decide. In the US, anybody born before 1800 was deemed to be public domain.

Answer (score 8):

The easy answer is that you couldn't, at least not with the information available, and this is still true of any famous figure, even those we have a lot of data on, as you still only get a small slice of any public figure's life and personality preserved in records no matter what you do.  Even assuming you had a thorough enough understanding of how the brain works to reconstruct brain bits without direct structural information, the data just wouldn't be there.

Of course, in a worldbuilding context, you can kind of handwave anything that sounds plausible within the context of your world.  Accessing memories via genetic code is insane and has no basis, but it's also the fundamental conceit of the Assassin's Creed universe.  There are a few options that would at least be plausible in a storytelling context.

1. The Holographic Principle: The holographic principle is a solution to the problem of information loss via hawking radiation as a black hole evaporates.
   The essential idea behind it is that all of the information concerning what is in the black hole is stretched around the surface of it, sort of like a 3-d image can be represented as a bunch of random bumps on a piece of holographic material, which one can only see by shining a light through the holographic material.  This saves the information about what has fallen into the black hole from being lost once it passes the event horizon, and provides a mechanism for that information to be encoded into the hawking radiation the black hole emits.  The cool part about this is that it appears to hold for *any* system with a horizon, including our own universe.  This means that, in theory, a sufficiently advanced entity residing outside our universe could get an accurate 3d picture of any part of it by analyzing its surface.  How that interacts with time, and whether our past is still scribbled on our horizon, is something of an open question, but even if it isn't, perhaps when someone dies their pattern radiates off like hawking radiation, able to be captured and interpreted by a sufficiently advanced civilization.  A more mystical variation of this would be something like an "akashic record" where the objective realities of the past are stored and can be accessed by those who know how.
2. Genetic Assassin's Creed Type Gibberish:  The idea of collecting the memories of one's ancestors from the genetic code is a bridge too far for me personally, and always ruins my immersion when this trope is used.  However, what you want isn't necessarily a person's memories, but their brain.  That brain was built by genes and those genes are distributed in the population.  In theory, if one could collect the stray bits and pieces of hundreds or thousands of a person's descendents, they could reconstruct their genome from those scattered pieces, and through it reconstruct their brain, at least in the state it was in when they were born.  In practice, this wouldn't work.  Recombination is a bitch and it only takes a few generations for parts of a genome to be lost forever, since not every bit will get passed on and not every bit that does will go to someone who passes it on in turn.  It's close enough to feasible for the handwaving of a storytelling universe to work with though.
3. Souls:  If people have souls that contain their personality, then all you need is an appropriate vessel to contain them, some magic to summon the soul you want, and a way to stick them together.  You could stick Caesar in a lawnmower if that's consistent with your universe.  Even this can be spun in a sciency way.  Physicist Roger Penrose has put forth the idea that the microtubules in a the brain preserve a superposition of quantum states that is responsible for consciousness and that this quantum state could theoretically outlast the physical brain.  Aging physicists often come up with crazy ideas and most of the scientific community does not entertain this one, but for a story it's great.  I can summon the spirits...er...access the persistent quantum states of ancient people and stick them into a machine or cloned body or something with a microtubule conformation that allows them to integrate with it.
4. Time Travel: Maybe you have some way to look into the past, and can directly observe, or even take samples from, the people you want to reconstruct.  This could be paradox free, no interaction time travel and and all interaction would happen with the reconstructed brain in the character's own time.

There are probably countless others I didn't think of, but all are going to require some degree of handwaving.  This is fine though.  The great thing about fiction is that your explanations don't have to actually be possible, just feasible enough to allow for suspension of disbelief within the context of your story.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that you don't. You could have biographers collect every piece of information about them recorded, dissect any surviving remains, take their general cultural background and known aspects of human nature and fill in the gaps with your best guess. A bit like asking an LLM to behave like a dead historical figure, but for all practical purposes the information in their brain is likely just gone.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers that there is insufficient information on the figures to even know with certainty exactly what happened in some key events, let alone have enough information to predict how they would react to "current" events.  (We lack the information to reconstruct Shakespeare's lost plays, so how can we model the person who wrote them?)  However, my frame challenge is:  Why would you want to?

Let's look at Julius Caesar.  A few of the things we can say with a fair level of certainty are:

1. He was an ambitious politician who, for a time, maintained the support of the elite in a slave-owning society which considered Romans to be superior to everyone else.
2. He was a military leader whose forces conquered significant areas using melee weapons and a very limited array of short-ranged weapons.
3. He kept his military forces happy and loyal with the loot, including slaves, captured in his conquests.  Let's not forget that rape and pillage were literally the standard reward for a victorious army until quite recently (and unfortunately still are in some conflicts.)
4. He had no issues in using standard Roman strategies to keep conquered areas subservient, including forced relocations, collective punishments and brutal executions (eg crucifixion) as an example to others.

None of those leadership or pollitical abilities are useful or desirable in a modern, democratic society that respects human rights.  On the military side, while he clearly understood basic logistics in an agrarian society there is no reason that any of his expertise would translate to an industrial/post-industrial society engaged in hybrid warfare in land, air, water, space and cyberspace.  (Even officers who entered the military a few decades ago frequently struggle with the new realities, and they have been in a position to observe computer and other technology developments as they occurred.)

In summary, the brilliant minds of yesterday are probably not well suited to solving today's problems.  However, it is not an issue since they are completely unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want a system that does a full physics simulation for a given area.

Assume a coffin is a closed system with a reliable cycle of temperature (the less sealed the coffin is, the less likely it is to work).

Do a full molecule-by-molecule scan & upload of the coffin. Take all the physics down to the molecular level, but instead of running the physics simulation forward in time, run it backwards. Change the coffin environments to match general environments before time of internment (atmospheric levels, really). Eventually, you should be able to rewind to where the body was in a working state. Then pause, solve whatever was the cause of death, and simulate the brain going forward.

Worth noting, this will restore the brain to moment of death. The data between their peak and death is beyond "easy" reconstruction, so the simulation would result in the simulated brain having the mental capacity of someone on death's door, dying of old age and any related mental health issues they would have at that point. These would have to be simulated being cured, meaning memories lost before that point (to alzheimers, dementia, etc.) would remain lost as much as they would be to any normal alzheimers or demential patient who recovered.

Worth noting, to store data to simulate all the nerve cells in the brain would take about 5 exabytes of storage (this storage size is technically feasible in modern times if you had a data center the size of the mall of America dedicated to just the storage... this does not include processing, which would likely take a much larger facility with modern technology). However, with current progression in Hard Drive capacity growth, we increase by an order of magnitude every 5 years. This would mean by 2050 (about 26 years from now), the brain would be be able to fit on a high quality hard drive on an expensive desktop with the highest end graphics card used for parallel processing.

You'd likely need a large server room for simulating a given corpse back to the state where it could fit on that hard drive though. Give it to 2070, and that'd be desktop sized with the simulated brain fitting on something the size of a microsd.

Just in time to load up Johnny Silverhand.

Comment: I feel like if you had Laplace's Demon available to you and thus could run this sort of simulation and reconstruct a brain at the moment of death by running the clock back on a coffin full of dust and bones, getting from there to the brain in a healthier state would be child's play if you could already get from the dust to the degraded brain.

Comment: Not really. Consciousness throws a huge kink in the works due to self-reference. When you have a spinning loop, it's hard to see where it came from. With the decomposing body without consciousness, you basically just have Newtonian physics at play, and when you have a boundary condition, you'd just default to 'more brain like' instead of the guessing that you'd use Laplace's Demon for.

Comment: Laplace's Demon is a thought experiment about doing the sorts of reconstructions you are talking about.  It has nothing to do with consciousness.  Its a hypothetical agent that is capable of knowing the current state and motion of every particle in a system, and thus being able to predict how it evolves.

Comment: I'm quite aware of Laplace's Demon. The thing is, I'm not talking about a hypothetical. In bioinformatics, we do molecule-by-molecule reconstructions and predictions all the time of "large" swaths of a cell at any given time. It does take a lot of computing power, but it is regularly done. The problem with consciousness is its self-reference. Consciousness basically contains patterns where things are their own cause, at which point the accuracy of the simulation gets very shaky, so trying to reconstruct backwards further back than once they have consciousness would likely fail.

Comment: My degree is in systematics and evolution.  I have done a fair amount of work in bioinformatics and yes, you are very much talking about a hypothetical.  Reconstructing some bacterial genomes from a soil sample isn't the same as reconstructing a brain from a coffin full of dust...like at all.  Also no, the problem with consciousness isn't self reference.  We have no idea how consciousness works or what "the problem" is with it but I'd bet money causality breaking magic isnt it.  You cant just use sciency sounding words with confidence and expect that to make a statement correct.

Comment: @Jeremiah Yes, doing it on the scale of a human is hypothetical, but the tech of running a physics simulation on a molecule configuration is not. I've also worked in bioinformatics too, specifically in analysing protein bonding in the human brain. They're all just molecular interactions which is what the software is. It actually doesn't matter if it's a living creature or not, for the most part. If molecules continue to act according to normal physics, it's *mostly* able to be simulated.

Comment: @Jeremiah Further, the problem with consciousness is absolutely self-reference. This isn't some magical unknown. You need to take your nose out of your own field and look at the research other fields have been doing. The neurosciences have pretty much nailed down what consciousness is now, it's not some big magical mystery you're making it out to be. It's the capacity of self-reference cycles. You have branching paths in cognition, but those branching paths include checking state of those branching paths. Multiple fields have confirmed this, from neurology to endocrinology to psychology.

Comment: @Jeremiah And that self-reference is a problem for simulations because once you include self-reference to where you can get a single state resulting from multiple origin states, there's not much you can do to re-wind, but as long as you're in the chemical equivalent of "the boulder rolled this way down", we can rewind it "back up the hill".

Comment: Confidently incorrect gibberish.  Again, when you just use sciency sounding words you only think you inderstand to spew gibberish that doesn't make sense it shows your hand.  No, we don't know how consciousness works and no, self reference isn't what makes simulating consciousness difficult.  Complexity is the issue here, not "self reference".  If you want to challenge that statement, please include a source, and I will read it so make sure it's actually making your case, which means making sure you actually understand it.  It will be apparent if that isn't the case.

Comment: The human brain is quite literally the most complex object in the known universe.  This is true whether it's currently in a conscious state or not.  That is what makes simulating it a problem.  By all means dig your hole deeper but this is the crux of the issue.  You are vastly underestimating the entropy of this system and then trying to blame some sort of magical "self reference" for what is a much easier to understand problem.  Sorry, recursion isn't the magic behind consciousness no matter what the memes may have told you.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that the human mind is one of the most complex things known, largely due to the feedback loops that create consciousness (I don't get why you think self reference is some sort of magic. You might as well claim addition is magic. You'll need citations that it's not what's behind consciousness, as most research I've read says otherwise.) But yea, that's why the simulations would only be able to rewind until it stops being inert. Once the brain is functioning, even if not conscious (since it still has those loops acting), it becomes too difficult to roll back further.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a magical component to your story, I think there are ways to get around your problem, i.e. having a kind of mage who is able to call forth a sort of mirror of a personality from the past that in some way could be scanned and interpreted by modern tech for reproduction.
Otherwise, I agree with other commenters that instead of the AI being designed to recreate a specific person from history, they might instead represent an aggregate of the best traits and strategic ideas from historic figures, given the desired functionality of the AI entities. For better or worse, this reminds me of a GI Joe cartoon storyline where they genetically bound together traits of several historic figures to make a formidable super villain.
Good luck!